# Optimize Einstein Summation with Repeating Matrices but Different Subscript

Tags: algorithm, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication, numpy-einsum

*Disclaimer:* I *did* though about posting to math stack-exchange or some kind. But I heard from my math-major friends that they don't really use Einstein Summation a lot, but I do know machine learning uses a lot of that. Therefore I posted this problem here (as optimizing algorithm performance).

When doing research about matrix computation (e.g. how many element wise multiplications are at least needed), I was trying to compute the following gradient:

[image: high level equation]

where **`ABC` means contract three matrices on their first axis** (e.g. `2x3`, `2x4`, and `2x5` becomes `3x4x5` with the `2`-axis summed over). Basically, it computes the gradient of norm of 3-matrix-contraction `ABC` with respect to `A`. Then computes the norm of that gradient with respect to `A` again.

This is equivalent to:

[image: traditional writing]

or simplify a little bit (proven by `autograd`):

[image]

We can write this in Einstein Summation form (used by `einsum` function of a lot of packages such as `numpy`, `tensorflow` and etc.)

```
np.einsum('ia,ib,ic,jb,jc,jd,je,kd,ke->ka', A, B, C, B, C, B, C, B, C)
```

When writing this, I find matrices `B` and `C` are kind of repeating again and again in the summation. I'm wondering can I **simplify those "lots of B and Cs" to matrix power** of some kind? That should make things logarithmic-ly faster. I tried manually simplifying but didn't figure out.

Thanks a lot! Please correct me if something I'm saying is not correct.

Comment: An optimal solution to your proposed problem is incredible difficult to figure out and something we talk about [here](https://github.com/dgasmith/opt_einsum/issues/65). In the meantime you might want the ability to automatically stash intermediates which likely will help you a great deal, see the docs [here](https://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sharing_intermediates.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can first broadcast (i.e. outer product) `B` (of shape `ib`) and `C` (of shape `ic`) to get a `BC` tensor of shape `ibc`:

```
BC = np.einsum('ib,ic->ibc', B, C)
```

I can then tensor contract it with its transpose to get a square matrix:

```
JUMP = np.einsum('ibc,cbj->ij', BC, BC.T)
```

This matrix `JUMP` is square and acts like "gradient jump" operator that jumps order of gradient. For example, If I want to get the second order gradient as mentioned in the question, I can simply multiply this `JUMP` with the first order gradient to get that:

```
g2 = JUMP @ g1
```

To get the third order, multiply matrix square of it:

```
g3 = JUMP @ JUMP @ g1
```

To get forth order, multiply matrix forth-power (not cube) of it:

```
g4 = np.linalg.matrix_power(JUMP, 4) @ g1
```

Comment: the point of einsum is that you shouldn't need to order your indices before argument insertion since the specification is explicit: `np.einsum('ibc,cbj->ij', BC, BC.T)` is the same as `np.einsum('ibc,jbc->ij', BC, BC)`, fyi.